# Difference in shape of np array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

What is the difference between an numpy array of shape (10,1) and (10,)?
Is there a way to change the array from shape (10,1) to (10,)?

Comment: 1. Just print the arrays with the different shapes 2. See the `reshape` function

Answer (score 3):

A shape of `(3,1)` filled with `1`'s would look like: `[[1], [1], [1]]`, while a shape of `(3,)` filled with `1`'s would be: `[1, 1, 1]`. You can use `np.reshape` to change between shapes that have the same number of elements: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html